# How can I convert my angular 5 based website to mobile app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to build the mobile app (Android, IOS, Windows) using my existing Angular 5 based project. In my Angular project, I have used PHP/MYSQL as backend and DB. I am web programmer but new to Mobile apps.

I also learned about the ionic framework but ionic has own tags and it depends on other techniques.

Can anyone guide how can I save my time to code again for the Mobile app?

It would be very thankful.

Comment: I guess best option is to use ionic framework. If you want to build native apps, you have to learn lot's of new languages and frameworks... etc. And if you are familiar with javascript react native could be a good option. Can I ask why you do not want to use ionic?

Comment: The easiest way to do it would definitely be ionic, yeah it has its own tags but they are pretty much the same, there is no magic way to convert angular 5 code into mobile ready code

Comment: Thanks, all. I know there is no magic way to convert but which is the best in my situation ionic framework or javascript react native or one more is read i.e Phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, as you told you have already developed an application using Angular. So, you have no choice except build a mobile app using the ionic framework.

In your case, the advantage of ionic is that some additional work will be required in ionic but no need to build a mobile app from zero.

So, my suggestion is you can go with the ionic framework.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Akash for the guideline. Actually, that is what I needed.